# Reporting Services 3.0 Chart calling stored procedure with date time value , how to sort?

Tags: datetime-format, reportbuilder3.0

I have a Stored Procedure in SQL Server 2008. One of the values returned is:

SELECT DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,e.Day), 0) AS [Month],

So I get values like: 2012-05-01 00:00:00.000

I want to display the month in the X axis for a chart report, obviously sorted chronologically. It would be great if I can display the month as "May-2012" or "2012 - May". Right now it displays the whole thing as 5/1/2012 12:00:00 AM and it is sorted alphabetically instead of by month.

When I check the Sorting it shows the field [Month] and order A to Z, so I assume it is not "seeing" it as a datetime value.

1. How do I get the sorting right?
2. How do I change the format to display the month as "May-2012" ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

OK, work around:

I talked to my DBA, asked him to return a formatted field from the stored procedure, with values like "2012-05" and '2012-12' and sort by that field. Then I used that new field on the Report builder Chart, and remove all sorting.

Works for now, but still need to understand how to do it right for future reports.